# Nant errors displayed in summary of job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build-process, build-automation, nant

I used CCNet before for my builds and there was a clever plugin to parse errors from NAnt and display it in summary of the build. Now i try to move to Jenkins and have problem with that. I  want to have errors displayed in summary of given build but have no idea how to do this. When error in NAnt occur the only solution for now is: go to Console Output and find error manually. Maybe someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're building, there are various plugins that may help:

- [Violations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations)
- [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin)
- [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin)

A full list can be found on the [Jenkins Plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins)

Comment: I have all those plugins already. But dont have idea how to configure for example Log Parser Plugin to find errors in NAnt?

Comment: There are configuration details and examples for the `Log Parser Plugin` on that linked page. Basically create a configuration file specifying the rules you require, upload it to your Jenkins server, add it to the global configuration, and select it in your job. The instructions there are fairly detailed - perhaps if you say which part is tripping you up I may be able to help further.

Comment: I have an issue with correct regex for .net builds (msbuild and nant) I don't know how to setup is correctly to find only errors from msbuild and nant execution

Comment: Update the post with some relevant details (ie, what you have so far, and an error you're trying to highlight) and I'll take a look